# Filling deep gaps at corners of maple flooring

Tags: wood, floor

I have fairly new natural maple 3/4" [about 4" wide] flooring installed. The installer was sloppy and where the flooring butted against doorways (no doors, just open frames), he should have side cut the vertical door moldings and placed the planks under, but he just straight cut and I have gaps. In the worst case I have an L shaped hole, 3/4" deep, 1/2" wide and about 3"x3".

As a result food from the adjacent kitchen, and water and anything can get in these spaces. I've though of filling with white silicon caulk to match the white moldings, or maybe beige to try and match the floor.  But I'm thinking that 3/4" deep is too much for that.

I have matching planks, so I could cut possible cut a couple of 1/2" pieces for the big gaps, but that won't work for the narrow gaps. I'm skilled in woodworking.

Comment: A photo or two might be helpful.

Comment: You pay this guy in full? This sounds like this guy needs to fix this himself, I have never seen an installer do this anywhere

Comment: Yep - you should see some of the other crap he did, painted over the interior wires on track lights, messed up my vacuum system, failed to ground some outlets, broke some kitchen tiles by insisting he knew how to make a transition transom better  than I did. Depended which worker did the work,the one who messed up was also stealing from the contractor. In the end the whole job was priced far lower than it should have been, so I;m ok pricewise.

Comment: Sure sounds like a sloppy job. there are caulks especially for matching wood floor colors. you could use them, but I would be screaming to have it done right. Guess you learned that you normally get what you pay for. sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Patching with the scrap flooring where you have a big enough gaps seems the best idea.

You also could use small shoe or stop molding around the base of the door jamb and casing (assuming the casing is not too complex). Paint it to match the trim. It will largely disappear.